# How can I get the indexPath of an UIScrollView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, nsindexpath

I have a `UITableViewCell` with a `UIScrollView`:

```
cellScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 43)];
cellScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(960, 43);
cellScroll.contentOffset = CGPointMake(320, 0);
cellScroll.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
[cell addSubview:cellScroll];
```

With a `UIButton` this problem is solved with this code:

```
UIView *animationView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 960, 43)];
[cellScroll addSubview:animationView];

cellButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
cellButton.frame = CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 43);
[cellButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didPushCellButton:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[animationView addSubview:cellButton];

- (void)didPushCellButton:(id)sender event:(id)event {        
NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:theTable];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [theTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:currentTouchPosition];
}
```

I tried this also with the `UIScrollView`, but that did not work.
Further I tried also some other things with gestures and more.
But nothing works.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you explain when and why you need the `indexPath` since it looks like your button code is already working?  That might help someone understand the context and help you out.

Comment: For the `UIButton` it works, but not for a `UIScrollView` and that is the problem. I said: "With a UIButton this problem is solved with this code:"